# Why is index a class of some sort and not an integer?

Tags: reactjs, methods

In the code below, the handle function is printing Class to the console, instead of the index. How to get the handle method to print out the index?? I am passing the index from the map function to the handle method.

```
class Sample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            folks: [
                {name: "Phil", age: 22},
                {name: "Zander", age: 39},
                {name: "Tobias", age: 37}
            ]
        }
    }

    handle(i) {
        console.log(i)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <ul>
                    {this.state.folks.map((person, index) => {
                        return (
                        <li onClick={ index => {this.handle(index)}} key={index + " person"} >
                        {person.name} {person.age}
                        </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Sample />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: this is confusing, you have `.map((person, index) =>` and also `onClick={ index => ` basically you are using the same variable name as parameter in 2 functions.

Comment: @apokryfos huh?!? Do you even know what you’re saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be re-declaring your index variable. Do this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <ul>
                {this.state.folks.map((person, index) => {
                    return (
                    <li onClick={() => {this.handle(index)}} key={index + " person"} >
                    {person.name} {person.age}
                    </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Ok my bad that solved the issue. What I thought is that index is being passed from the map function to the arrow function and then onward to the handle method.

Comment: Indeed, the index within the `onClick` method was actually a click event object